# What is the probability of a random variable larger than or equal to any other independent random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, order-statistics

Suppose random variables $X_1$, $X_2$,..., and $X_n$ are independent and normally distributed (with varied means and variances), what is $P(X_i\ge \max_{j\in [1,n], j\neq i} \{X_j\})$?

Comment: Assuming that the $X_i$ all have the same distribution, it's $1/n$ as above. Do you mean for it to be generic normal distributions, with possibly differing means and variances?

Comment: @Dougal in my case, the means and variances are varying.

Comment: In that case, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4138/what-is-the-probability-that-random-variable-x-1-is-maximum-of-random-vector, where in your case $\Sigma$ will be diagonal, though maybe that leads to a simpler closed-form case.

Comment: @Dougal the link is what I am looking for, thx. But I still got a question if a multivariate normal distribution with a diagonal sigma matrix is equivalent to multiple independent univariate normal distributions?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normally_distributed_and_independent). You can prove it by just writing out the pdf for a diagonal-$\Sigma$ multivariate normal and observing that it factors into exactly the product of independent univariate normals.